# Why can a pointer to class can change value via function call?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am new to pointer to class.I write simple code to show my question.
Why can p->num set value in f2? Pointer p isn't like n ? Just a local variable? 
Aren't both n1 and p2 's scope only in f1 and f2 separately ?  thanks
What is different between them!

```
class Node{
public:
   int num;
   Node* next;
};

void f1(Node n1){
   n1.num = 50;
}
void f2(Node*p2){
   p2->num= 100;
}
int main(){     
   Node n;
   f1(n);
   cout<<n.num<<endl;//output 0

   Node*p;
   f2(p);
   cout<<p->num<<endl;//output 100
   return 0;    
}
```

Comment: `Node*p; f2(p);` is undefined behavior as-is. Your `p` doesn't point anywhere. Also, **use whitespace.** Seriously. Code w/o whitespace is hard to read. As to why can a value be modified through a pointer: because that's how memory access works. You grab an address, dereference it, write to the memory at that address.

Comment: Because you're invoking undefined behavior. Anything can happen (I only wish that *anything* included my house somehow painting itself). The passed variable `p` is **indeterminate**. It has no stated value. Using it for evaluation *in any way* is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Note that p doesn't actually point to anything, as you never allocated a Node for it to point to.  Similarly, you never initialized num in n.

Comment: You can change class members via pointer. That's the point of introducing pointers in the first place (well, one of the points anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is really printing `100` for you, you're extremely lucky (or unlucky, based on the point of view). There's a problem that `p` is not pointing to anything, so when you write through it, you write into random memory. You should initialise it, perhaps like this:

```
int main(){     
   Node n;
   f1(n);
   cout<<n.num<<endl;//output 0

   Node *p = &n;  //now `p` will point to the Node object `n`
   f2(p);
   cout<<p->num<<endl;//output 100
   return 0;    
}
```

This could also help answer your primary question: a pointer *points to* an existing object. Which means that while `p2` is indeed local in `f2()`, it's a copy of the pointer `p` from `main()`. And they both point to the same object (object `n` in my modification), which is why `f2()` can modify an "external" object through its local copy of the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Passing a pointer to a function is like passing by reference. I fact, that's basically how references work under the hood.

Also, you have *undefined behavior* in your code, for both cases. When you declare a local variable without assigning to it at the same time, it's value is *indeterminate*, and using that value for anything is undefined. Yes, even accessing `n.num` is undefined behavior, that you get the value `0` for that is just luck. And using a pointer like you do may even cause the program to crash.

Comment: You think someone who doesn't understand pointers understands references?

Comment: * how references are *emulated* in C. (since C has no references.)

Answer (score 1):

```
f1(n);
```

`n` is passed by copy. Therefore, it's value doesn't change in `main()`.

```
f2(p);
```

`p` is passed by copy. However, `p` is a pointer and you are changing the value to where it points. Therefore, the value to what it points can be updated and seen in `main()`.

Don't forget to allocate the memory to where `p` points.

```
Node n;
Node *p;
p = &n;
```